# How we can select item from drop down combo box using value of element in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to know how we can select a value from drop down combo box using value of that item.

**Below is the form tag**

```
<form id="rahul" onkeypress="EnterHandler();" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" action="./RequestSubmission?CC8510F49CCCF2&" method="post">
<div class="rcbSlide" style="z-index: 6000; visibility: visible; display: block; overflow: visible; margin-left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 575.2px; left: 768.183px; height: 202px; width: 300px;">
<div id="ctl00_MainContent_ucAdditionalDetailsMAP_txtResponsiblePerson_DropDown" class="RadComboBoxDropDown RadComboBoxDropDown_MetroTouch rcbAutoWidth rcbAutoWidthResizer" style="display: block; visibility: visible; top: 0px; left: 0px; transition: none 0s ease 0s ;">
<div class="rcbScroll rcbWidth rcbNoWrap" style="height: 200px; width: 100%; overflow: auto;">
<ul class="rcbList" style="list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;zoom:1;">
<li class="rcbItem">Aava, Ruth</li>
<li class="rcbItem">Abdelgawwad, Khaled</li>
<li class="rcbItem">Achcar, Cecilia</li>
<li class="rcbItem">Achilles, Karin</li>
<li class="rcbItem">Adachi, Masatoshi</li>
<li class="rcbItem">admin, bayer</li>
<li class="rcbItem">Adriane, Fernandes</li>
<li class="rcbItem">Aeschliman, Lisa</li>
<li class="rcbItem">Afonja, Olubunmi</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

**Here is the div tag from where we are selecting the value from drop down combo box.**

```
<div id="ctl00_MainContent_ucAdditionalDetailsMAP_txtResponsiblePerson" class="RadComboBox RadComboBox_MetroTouch" style="width:350px;">
<table class="" style="border-width: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;" summary="combobox">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="rcbInputCell rcbInputCellLeft" style="width:100%;">
<input id="ctl00_MainContent_ucAdditionalDetailsMAP_txtResponsiblePerson_Input" class="rcbInput radPreventDecorate rcbEmptyMessage" type="text" value="Select" name="ctl00$MainContent$ucAdditionalDetailsMAP$txtResponsiblePerson" autocomplete="off">
</td>
<td class="rcbArrowCell rcbArrowCellRight">
<a id="ctl00_MainContent_ucAdditionalDetailsMAP_txtResponsiblePerson_Arrow" style="overflow: hidden;display: block;position: relative;outline: none;">select</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I want to know how we can select li item "Aava, Ruth" in selenium webdriver using its value.

Comment: You should provide code you tried so far and obstacles you faced

Comment: @Andersson
I had performed two clicks for selecting value from dropdown

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(//*[@id='ctl00_MainContent_ucAdditionalDetailsMAP_txtResponsiblePerson']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(//div[@id='ctl00_MainContent_ucAdditionalDetailsMAP_txtResponsiblePerson_DropDown']/div/ul/li[1]))).click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below XPath

```
//ul[@class='rcbList']/li[1]
```

OR

```
//ul[@class='rcbList']/li[contains(.,'Aava, Ruth')]
```

You can select it directly by using below code:-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='rcbList']/li[1]")).click();
```

Note:- First click on dropbox then use above code

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I already tried this and its working for me. I don't want to use li[1] or li[2] as my dropdown list is continously changing. So i want a way by which i can select it by its value.

Comment: Ok .. I have added one more xpath in my answer .. it will work too according to your text

Comment: Thanks li[contains(.,'Aava, Ruth')] is working for me.